# Contact form 7 WP, additional text field after choosing one option

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I use on my page Contact Form 7 (Wordpress). In one form I need to add a appearing text field when the user choose "Other" option from menu. How can I make this?

Comment: please update your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or jquery for this.

You can call a function on selection of the dropdown and check if the value is others, then make an input text appear with .html function of jquery.